# Java: Overriding Generic Method with Typed Method?

Tags: java, inheritance, casting, overriding

I have a parent class EntryPoint with an abstract method to retrieve a prop that is a list of a generic type. The list is declared as protected:

```
public abstract class EntryPoint implements Serializable {

    public EntryPoint(){}

    protected ArrayList<? extends Tag> tiedTags;

    public abstract ArrayList<? extends Tag> getTiedTags();

}
```

I have a child class representative of an SNMP Entry Point (used for querying an SNMP agent). IntelliJ is not complaining about this configuration but I am wondering, am I correctly overriding the getTiedTags() method from the parent or have I somehow overwritten the parent method?

```
public class SNMPEntryPoint extends EntryPoint implements Serializable {

    //Default Constructor for Serialization
    public SNMPEntryPoint(){}

    @Override
    public ArrayList<SNMPTag> getTiedTags(){ return (ArrayList<SNMPTag>) tiedTags; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleaner way would probably be to introduce a type parameter on the class level

```
public abstract class EntryPoint<T extends Tag> implements Serializable {

    public EntryPoint(){}

    protected ArrayList<T> tiedTags;

    public abstract ArrayList<T> getTiedTags();

}
```

and then inherit via

```
public class SNMPEntryPoint extends EntryPoint<SNMPTag> implements Serializable {

    //Default Constructor for Serialization
    public SNMPEntryPoint(){}

    @Override
    public ArrayList<SNMPTag> getTiedTags(){ return tiedTags; }
}
```

at which point the cast is no longer needed.

Comment: I am just now learning about how to use generics so thank you for this. I can't believe I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 3):

The method you are overriding is not a generic method; a generic method declares its own type variables.

The override in `SNMPEntryPoint` is a *covariant override*; a subclass is allowed to override a method in a superclass to return a more specific type (a subtype of the original type) than the return type in the overridden method, such as:

```
interface Factory {
    Object make();
}

class StringFactory implements Factory {
    @Override
    String make() { ... }
}
```

Since `ArrayList<SNMPTag>` is a subtype of `ArrayList<? extends Tag>`, your example is a valid (though unusual) covariant override.

There is no corresponding feature for overriding a method whose argument types are *less specific*.

Comment: This helps. I assumed that I was overriding because the original method was abstract, but I wasn't exactly sure how to generify a class at the class level or a method for that matter.

Comment: When you mention there being no corresponding feature for overriding a method whose argument types are less specific, if Tag is an abstract class, and I have a list of Tags in my EntryPoint class as shown above, and I am sure all of the tags in that list are actually more specific objects such as SNMPTags, would a covariant overrride such as the one above give me meaningful access to functions and attributes relative to that specific subclass? I.e. if only SNMPTags contain an OID String and I want to call getOID() on each of the SNMPEntryPoint's tags, would a covariant override do the job?

Comment: It sounds like you want the approach suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67220445/3553087